# Переменная в классе Null

Tags: ооп, классы, php, объекты, mvc

Здравствуйте!
Есть класс

```
class page
{ 
  public $get;

  function __construct()
  {
    $array = Routing::GET();
    $this->get = $array;
  }
}
```

Он расширяется так

```
Class index extends page
  {
    function index()
    {
        var_dump($this);
    }

  }
```

При выводите var_dump, я узнаю что переменная $get равна NULL,

```
object(index)#4 (1) { ["get"]=> NULL }
```

Хотя в конструкторе я указал что она будет равна результату функции

```
Routing::GET();
```

В переменную $array все нормально попадает. В чем проблема?

Comment: А вы уверены, что `Routing::GET();` получает значение? :)

Comment: покажи содержимое метода GET класса Routing

Comment: @intro94 Уверен, я писал что в $array все правильно входит.

     $array = Routing::GET();
     print_r($array); // Выведет все правильно

Comment: Формально все правильно. Если захреначить `var_dump()` в конструктор, он отработает?

Comment: покажите как вы вызываете index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не в том, что получает get, а в том, что конструктор не срабатывает, я думаю это из за того что нет явного обращения к переменной.